# MySQL JSON_EXTRACT with LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb

Let's say we have a column of JSON Arrays with a relatively large number of elements:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|              |
|   user_id    |            badges 
|              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    123456    |  '["a", "b","c", "d", ... "yz", "zz"]'
|    345678    |  '["1", "2","3", "4", ... "701", "702"]'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to get the elements in small batches similar to using LIMIT and OFFSET on non-JSON queries?

For example: to fetch elements from 51 to 61:

```
SELECT badges->>$[*] FROM user_table WHERE user_id = '123456' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 50;
```

Comment: As an aside, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL 8+ you can use `JSON_TABLE` to split the JSON array into rows, creating an extra column which represents the index in the array (starting from 1). You can then use that column in a `WHERE` clause. For example:

```
SELECT u.user_id,
       b.badge
FROM user_table u
JOIN JSON_TABLE(u.badges,
                '$[*]' COLUMNS
                (rn FOR ORDINALITY,
                 badge VARCHAR(20) PATH '$'
                 )) b
WHERE user_id = '123456' 
  AND b.rn BETWEEN 2 and 4
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
user_id     badge
123456      b
123456      c
123456      d
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gruhbGEzzjxqruM6JNuj2K/0)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. But wouldn't it be too taxing to create full tables on each request? Especially when badges array element count increases over time.

Comment: @monroo `JSON_TABLE` is actually reasonably performant when you restrict the input. But if you're really concerned about performance, you should properly normalise your table and store badges in a `user_badges` table (`id`, `user_id`, `badge_id`). Then you *can* simply use LIMIT and OFFSET to select the rows you want.